# How to multiply each channel separately with same matrix?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a 1 and 3 channeled `Mat`s of the same size, call them `a` and `img`. I want to multiply each channel of `img` with `a`. And I will perform this many times, performance is an issue.

Is there a way of using the `multiply()` operations or multiply operator overloads to benefit from the optimizations in OpenCV? I am trying to avoid writing my own loop for performance reasons, using operators leads to much clean code too.

I don't want to repeat `a` three times and `merge()` into a single 3-channeled `Mat` because of performance issues.

Comment: What's your typical image size? What is time limit for this operation? Some hardware limitation (PC, smartphone, embedded)?

Comment: The size is around 80x120, but I will have to do this operation at least million times at each run.

Comment: I assume 1M times with different values of a and img each time, right? Do you have all 1M values at the beginning, or you retrieve the current value at each iteration? What would be a reasonable time for all 1M operations?

Answer (score 1):

> > Is there a way of using the multiply() operations or multiply operator overloads to benefit from the optimizations in OpenCV?

OpenCV3 pushes the use of the `cv::UMat` class in place of `cv::Mat`. This should give you a little GPU acceleration where possible.

> > I am trying to avoid writing my own loop for performance reasons, using operators leads to much clean code too.

I would disagree, `performance reasons` is probably wrong because you will depend on whatever compilation was used to build the libs. If the lib doesn't have AVX2, you will loose performance. Further, you will be limited to OpenCV's primitives which drastically increase memory access. Specifically, each time you do something like `cv::add(A,B,C)` followed by `cv::sqrt(C,C)` you hit the memory an extra time resulting in a notable performance decrease.

It also definitely not cleaner code, more like writing scripts for an old [Polish Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) calculator.

In summary, if you have performance concerns grab the `.data()` pointer, check if it vectorizes, and do your work in C++/CUDA/OCL.